# Gradient of a function with respect to a matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

How can I compute the gradient of the following function with respect to $X$,

$$g(X) = \frac{1}{2}\|y-AX\|^2$$

where $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and $A:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear. We can assume that $A$ is of the form,

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}\langle X| A_1\rangle\\\vdots\\\langle X|A_m\rangle\end{pmatrix}$$

where $A_1,\ldots,A_m$ are $n\times n$ real matrices and the inner product is the Frobenius inner product.

Edit: my attempt at finding the gradient,

$$g(X+H) = \frac{1}{2}\langle y-A(X+H), y-A(X+H)\rangle,\\
= \frac{1}{2} \langle y-AX-AH, y-AX-AH\rangle,\\
=\frac{1}{2} \left(\langle y-AX, y-AX\rangle -\langle y-AX,AH\rangle -\langle AH, y-AX\rangle +o(\|H\|)\right),\\
=g(X) - \langle y-AX, AH\rangle,\\
=g(X)-\langle A^*\left(y-AX\right),H\rangle,\\
\implies \nabla g(X) = -A^*\left(y-AX\right)$$

Now I must compute the adjoint operator $A^*$ of $A$.

To find $A^*$ we do the following,

$$\langle y, AX\rangle = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m y_i\langle X, A_i\rangle=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \langle X, y_iA_i\rangle = \langle X, \sum\limits_{i=1}^my_iA_i\rangle$$

to see that $A^*y = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m y_iA_i$. Applying this to the expression we found above gives,

$$\nabla_Xg(X) = -A^*(y-AX) = -\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\left(y_i-\mbox{tr}(X^TA_i)\right)A_i.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $g(X)=1/2(y-A(X))^T(y-A(X))$ is

$Dg_X:Y\in M_n\rightarrow -(A(Y))^T(y-A(X))$.

$(A(Y))^T(y-A(X))=[tr(Y^TA_1),\cdots,tr(Y^TA_m)][y_1-tr(X^TA_1),\cdots,y_m-tr(X^TA_m)]^T=$

$\sum_{i\leq m}tr(Y^TA_i)(y_i-tr(X^TA_i))=tr(Y^T\sum_{i\leq m}(y_i-tr(X^TA_i))A_i)$.

Conclusion. The gradient of $g$ is

$\nabla(g)(X)=-\sum_{i\leq m}(y_i-tr(X^TA_i))A_i$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}\def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\unvec#1{\operatorname{unvec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Reshape the matrix variables into their corresponding vectors
$$\eqalign{
x &= \vec{X} &\qif X = \unvec{x} \\
a_k &= \vec{A_k} &\qif A_k = \unvec{a_k} \\
}$$
Then construct the matrix
$$\eqalign{
B &= \m{a_1 & a_2& \ldots & a_m}^T \qiq A(X)=Bx \\
}$$
This results in a vector problem with a well known solution
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \frac 12\|Bx-y\|^2 \qiq \grad{\phi}{x}= B^T(Bx-y) \\
}$$
The only remaining task is to reshape this into a *matrix-valued* gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{X} = \unvec{\grad{\phi}{x}} \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write the cost function as
$\phi 
= \frac{1}{2} \sum_i z_i^2
$
with $z_i=
\mathrm{tr}
\left( \mathbf{A}_i^T \mathbf{X} \right)
-y_i
$.

Then taking a differential approach,
we obtain
$$
d\phi 
= \sum_i z_i 
\mathrm{tr}
\left( \mathbf{A}_i^T d\mathbf{X} \right)
=
\mathrm{tr}
\left( 
\sum_i z_i 
\mathbf{A}_i^T d\mathbf{X} \right)
$$
The gradient is thus
$\sum_i z_i \mathbf{A}_i$.